# Proving functions are uniformly continuous help!

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, uniform-continuity

a) Prove that $f(x)=x^{1/4}$ is uniformly continuous on $[0,\infty)$. Show that this method can be extended inductively to any $f(x)=x^{1/p}$ for any $p=2^n$

b) Prove directly from the definition that $f(x)=(1+x^2)^{1/2}$ is uniformly continuous on
$\mathbb{R}$.

For part a I know how to prove it if $x^{1/2}$ but I'm unsure how to apply it for $x^{1/4}$ or any other p.

I'm not sure how to start b. any help would be very helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For part a) , show that for $f(x)=x^{1/4}$, $f'(x)$ is bounded in $(0, \infty)$, e.g., by finding $f'(x)$ at $x=1$, say, and then generalize to $f(x)=x^{1/2^n}$ . The mean value theorem should come in handy too.

EDIT: As Jochen pointed out, f'(x) is not bounded in $(0, \infty)$, tho it is bounded in $[c, \infty) ; c>0$. Then, as pointed out, we can use the fact that f is continuous in $[0,c]$ and then, by compactness of the interval, it is uniformly-continuous there, and by the rest of the argument, $f(x)$ is uniformly-continuous in $[0, \infty)$

Start by setting up an arbitrary $\epsilon$. Now you need to show that there is a single $\delta$ so that , for all $x,y$ , you have $$|f(x)-f(y)| < \epsilon $$ when $$|x-y|< \delta$$ . Can you see how to use the mean-value theorem to connect these two?

Comment: $f'(x)= \frac 14 x^{-3/4}$ is not bounded. However, it is bounded on $[1,\infty)$ which gives uniform continuity there and $f$ is uniformly continuous on $[0,2]$ because continuous functions on compact sets are always uniformly continuous.

Comment: @Jochen, yes, that is what I meant; that is why I referred to finding f'(x) at x=1. I'll edit.

Comment: so do I choose epsilon^4?

Comment: @user146296: I'm not sure of what you're aiming for, but you don't have to; you can use that $x^{1/4}$ has bounded derivative in , e.g., $[1,\infty)$ and that it is continuous in the compact interval $[0,1]$, using that if f is continuous on a compact interval then f is uniformly-continuous in that interval.

Comment: If you want to do a $\delta - \epsilon$ proof, then use MVT: $|x^4-y^4| =|1/4(w^{-3/4}(x-y)|\leq |M(x-y)|$ , where $M$ is an upper bound for $f'(x)=1/4 x^{-3/4}$ , and then set $(x-y)$ to be as small as you need (this is where you choose your $\delta$).

Comment: okay, I forgot that I could apply the MVT, however, I'm still confused on how to choose your delta with respect to epsilon.  Usually i choose delta=epsilon.  Could someone help me grasp what this even means? I know the |x-y|<delta  and |f(x)-F(y)|<epsilon  and M is the max value of f'(x) which I think is 1 when x=1?

Comment: One way to do it is to set $|x-y|< \epsilon/2M $. Then $|x^4-y^4|<|\frac {M \epsilon}{ 2M}|=\epsilon/2 <\epsilon$

Comment: The meaning of a $\delta - \epsilon $ argument is: you decide how close you need to be in your domain --this is given by $\delta$ for your function's values to be within $\epsilon$ of a given value $f(x)$. If y is within $\delta$ of $x$, i.e., formally, if $|x-y|< \delta$ , then the function value $f(y)$ will be within $\epsilon$ of $f(x)$, or formally, $|f(x)-f(y)|< \epsilon$. $|x-y| < \delta$ lives on the x-axis, and $|f(x)-f(y)|< \epsilon$ lives in the y-axis.